# Any advice on a 24 hour cyclical ketogenic diet

Tags: low-carb, ketogenic-diet, intermittent-fasting

I am a 43 year old man. I am 190cm tall and 85kg. I am slim with some belly fat. I am active, I do regular exercise and martial arts. My goal is to improve my general energy levels and sense of well being. I am also hoping to loose visceral fat and increase subcutaneous fat, and increase testosterone and growth hormone.

I have recently tried intermittent fasting, by delaying breakfast by 2 hours every day. I have a 16 hour period in the night and morning when I don't eat. I have also cut down on carbs a bit.

I feel very good and have more energy in general. Although I feel light headed and I little shaky in the mornings before breakfast.

I am interested to know if there maybe any benefits to cutting carbs even more, to the point where I would go into ketosis or semi-ketosis every morning before breakfast. I would then carb-up a little during the day, but by just the right amount so that I would go back into ketosis the next morning.

Is this a know diet strategy?

If so what might be the advantages or disadvantages of this approach over a constant keto diet or over a non-keto low carb diet?

Comment: My first thought is it takes weeks of an extremely low carb, high fat diet to actually get in to ketosis. You'd never reach that state doing this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I tried ketosis a year ago. It took a few days of no carbs. Say if I eat slightly more carbs than my threshold for ketosis, then surely I would go in and out of ketosis during different times of day.

Comment: Did you use ketone strips to test it? Most of the people I've met who practice ketosis took four to six weeks.

Comment: Yes I did use the test strips. I thought that it takes a few weeks to be adapted, to get over the keto flu. But not very long to go into ketosis.

Comment: Why you want to do this? What are your stats and what are your goals?

Comment: @wdika I will add this to the main body, to the original post.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question but i stil cannot understand why you want to do a keto diet. Also why have you made intermittent fasting and keto in the past? What is your current nutrition plan? What is your body fat? Those things you are saying it's all about lowering your body fat and losing weight. You can't expect to improve your energy levels by doing things for decreasing your body fat and losing weight. I am not saying that you won't have energy but you cannot improve it by those ways. Why are you stuck with those controversial methods for a middle athlete?

Comment: I tried ketosis out of curiosity, it was not right for me because I felt like I was getting too skinny. I am doing intermittent fasting now, and I have more energy, maybe my insulin sensitivity is improving. I am just wondering if I can push it further into some kind of mild ketosis because I have read about studies saying there are health benefits to having some ketones in the blood. My body fat reads quite high on one of those electronic resistance devices, but I look slim.

Comment: You must define what your needs and goals are. If you want to lose weight and decrease your body fat then do a diet with calorie deficit. If you want to gain weight - build muscle then go for a calorie surplus. If you want to keep your body where it is and balance your energy then go for a diet with the calories you need. With those methods you won't get any long term benefit. Keep a balanced diet based on your daily calories and macros, go for it with a proper training and rest. Your body energy will be at higher levels together with your brain energy. Mark both.

Comment: A ketogenic diet takes months of very low carbs to reach full ketones in your blood. From what I read in [this very helpful article](http://www.bodybuilding.com/content/ketogenic-dieting-frequently-asked-questions.html), eating over the carb limit will largely slow the goal of full ketones in your blood and I can attest to the crash that comes after too many carbs in the first month or two.  The article explains how you can transition into a Mediterranean diet and still be able to produce full blood ketones.